# How to update an object in typescript based on the key value?

Tags: typescript, object

I have the value of the key in the form of a string, and have to update the object based on the key value. Is there any method for doing this in typescript?

I tried using the <object_name>[key] = value method and it did not work

It gives the following error message:
`No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type '<type of object>'`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you do it like this:

```
let obj = { key: 'value' };
obj['key'] = 'new value';
```